# How to decode a coded sentence?

Tags: python

I'm not quite sure why StackOverflow won't allow me to post my code below, so I attached some links to show what I have tried. After typing out my sentence, it will shift any amount of characters from 1-25 which works just fine. However, I need to add a function which will reverse the encoding, and print the original sentence back out. I am not quite sure why Python is spitting out the decoded sentence, the way it does in the 2nd link. It should have the original sentence. Thanks for your help!

```
def encode( ch, shift):
    lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZ'
    if ch not in lower:
        return ch
    newch = chr( ord(ch) + shift )
    if newch not in lower:
        newshift = ( ord(newch) - ord('z') - 1)
        nwech = chr ( ord('a') + newshift )
    return newch

def decoded(ch, shift):
    lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZ'
    if ch not in lower:
        return ch
    newch = chr( ord(ch) + shift )
    if newch not in lower:
        newshift = ( ord(newch) - ord('z') - 1)
        newch = chr ( ord('a') + newshift)
    return newch

def main():
    shift = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 25:"))
    sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
    code = ''
    decode = ''
    for char in sentence:
        code = code + encode (char, shift)
    for char in code:
        decode = decode + encode (char, shift)
    print("Uncoded sentence: " + sentence)
    print("Encoded sentence: " + code)
    print("Decoded sentence: " + decode)

main()
```

```
Enter a number between 1 and 25:3
Please enter a sentence:i need help
Uncoded sentence: i need help
Encoded sentence: l qhhg khos
Decoded sentence: o tkkj nkrv
```

Comment: Include the code in the question, code in images are a pain; if you are slower than I am to type out your code manually and include it in the post.. well, you should work on your copy+past:ing skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `decoded` function seems to be the same as your `encode` function (and you're not calling it in any case). Closer to what you need is:

```
newch = chr( ord(ch) - shift )
```

in your `decoded` function, which you should call in place of `encode` here:

```
for char in code:
    decode = decode + decoded(char, shift)
```

But now you have another problem. What happens if your shift sends you off the end of the `ord` range for your characters?

Comment: Enter a number between 1 and 25:3
Please enter a sentence:i need help
Uncoded sentence: i need help
Encoded sentence: l qhhg khos
Decoded sentence:                             Now my decoded sentence is not     printing any sentence!

Comment: Your specific example will work... but try the same shift with a sentence containing x, y, or z...

Comment: Seems like I don't run into that problem. Enter a number between 1 and 25:5
Please enter a sentence:xyz
Uncoded sentence: xyz
Encoded sentence: cde
Decoded sentence:                             Now it's just my decoded sentence that is causing me problems.

Comment: Now I am running into that problem. Enter a number between 1 and 25:6
Please enter a sentence:i love science
Uncoded sentence: i love science
Encoded sentence: o rubk yioktik
Decoded sentence: i loĶe science                                                              But if I use a lower number: Enter a number between 1 and 25:2
Please enter a sentence:i love science
Uncoded sentence: i love science
Encoded sentence: k nqxg uekgpeg
Decoded sentence: i love science                                                               it works!

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the decode method. You call the encode method twice...